# How to specify directory-based coverageThreshold in nycrc?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, istanbul, nyc

I want to run coverage check on my coverage-final.json using `npx nyc report`
And I am able to do this, here is the output:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 66.67% ( 8/12 )
Branches     : 50% ( 2/4 )
Functions    : 100% ( 2/2 )
Lines        : 66.67% ( 8/12 )
================================================================================
```

Here you can see my `.nycrc.json`:

```
{
    "reporter": ["lcov", "text-summary"],
    "temp-dir": "coverage",
    "check-coverage": true,
    "branches": 10,
    "lines": 10,
    "functions": 10,
    "statements": 10
}
```

All seems to be ok, but I can't find any way to specify coverage thresholds for specific directories in my `.nycrc.json`. I want something similar to what [jest already has](https://runebook.dev/en/docs/jest/configuration#coveragethreshold-object) in order to apply different threshold values for different directories. Does someone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: I am also want to change the CWD of NYC,
but it deletes my code, I am finding the solution but have not found one yet